# ReadPreferences in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, client

Folks,

Any insights in to the algorithm / that determines the ReadPreferences. On how this is implemented in mongoDB.

```
 http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/
```

Thanks much!
_D

Comment: What algorithm? Read preference is a setting that determines where your reads are sourced from. What is the question you are actually asking.

Comment: As @NeilLun says it is a setting, by default there is no algorithm, it just picks primary. If you want to know the details behind a particular read preference setting then let us know